# In typescript, how can I import a plain javascript file with a default export using es6 syntax?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have a file in my typescript project that I want to be just plain JS, for reasons (not interested in hearing arguments for why that's good or bad).

Example Javascript file (named foo.js):

```
export default foo = { prop: 'value' }
```

Typescript file in same folder consuming above Javascript file

```
import foo from "./foo";
```

When I do this and try and run the typescript compiler, I get the following error:

> error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module './foo'.
>   '{fileLocation}/foo.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

I've read up on the documentation regarding declaration files a bit. In a real-world example, foo's object structure is not simple. and I DO NOT want to define it's structure just to use it in my project for time reasons.

Is there a simple straightforward way to declare this module as type any and move on with my day?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin allowJs works. In my project for some reason I'm still seeing the import underlined in VSCode with the warning about type declarations - but it does compile (weird).

One other gotcha I noticed is that `allowJs: true` and `declaration: true` cannot both be set at the same time. If removing `declaration: true` was not an option for a particular project - are there other options?

Comment: There are some workarounds (e.g. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7546#issuecomment-446472991) in the related TypeScript issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting `allowJs` in your `tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "allowJs": true 
  }
}
```

Aside: Your example [default export syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Syntax) is invalid. Here is a valid example:

```
export default { prop: 'value' }
```

Here is [a demo for fun](https://github.com/shaunluttin/typescript-import-plain-javascript-file).

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to create a typing file  foo.d.ts

```js
// foo.d.ts
declare module 'foo';
```

and set `noImplicitAny` to false on the tsconfig.json file:

```js
 "noImplicitAny": false,
```

Comment: You don't need both... `"noImplicitAny": false` is enough to silence any warnings when importing an untyped JS module.

Comment: In this particular environment, the team wants to keep noImplicitAny set to true, so that's not an option.

For the type declaration file, will the Typescript compiler find it without additional configuration if I put it in the same folder as foo.js?

Comment: I tried adding foo.d.ts adjacent to foo.js with above code. Now the error I'm getting is: `File '{fileLocation}/foo.d.ts' is not a module.`